# Site doesnt work once PHP changed to 7.1

Tags: php, mysql

I have just upgraded wordpress to version 4.7.3 on windows server 2008 R2.  mysql is currently at version 5.1.72 and php was at version 5.6.

Everything worked fine.

I then added PHP 7.1.1 to IIS and changed to that version and now I get a 500 error on the web page.

I disabled all the plug ins and I still get the error.  I reset the database password and I still get the error.

Is there anything else I can check/change/upgrade to resolve this?

Thanks

UPDATE

After enabling debug mode I get the following line in the error file

PHP Notice:  Undefined index: input in D:\Websites\MYWEBSITE\wp-includes\kses.php on line 866

Comment: Check the actual error log or set WP_DEBUG to TRUE in wp-config.php. You'll see the errors that are causing the 500 response code

Comment: I am a wordpress noob where does the error file get saved

Comment: That has nothing to do with WordPress. The error log is on your server, where that is depends on how your server is setup. There for just set WP_DEBUG to TRUE in wp-config as that will output the errors on screen.

Comment: ive updated my question based on error file, debug to true doesnt output errors on screen for me it just shows 500 error

Comment: A notice is not a 500 error.

Comment: Try run only PHP first on your server using any random php command. As, it is the issue of PHP configuration with server I guess.